# Java UncaughtExceptionHandler + LOG4J + Maven

Tags: java, maven, exception, log4j

I would like to log to a file all exceptions (shown in console) in my maven projects. I create a class witch implements UncaughtExceptionHandler and call the log4j Logger.error. This works in main maven project (where is the Main class), but not inside the others maven projects connected (with dependencies in all pom.xml). Maybe the default UncaughtExceptionHandler is overridden by Maven, but how can I make it works?

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
       Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(new DefaultExceptionHandler());
 }


public class DefaultExceptionHandler implements UncaughtExceptionHandler{

   private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(DefaultExceptionHandler.class);

@Override
public void uncaughtException(Thread thread, Throwable ex) {
    LOGGER.error("Exception thread: "+thread.getName(), ex);

}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

You can create instance of `java.io.PrintStream` as below

```
public static PrintStream createLoggingProxy(
            final PrintStream realPrintStream)
    {
        return new PrintStream(realPrintStream)
        {
            public void print(final String string)
            {
                logger.info(string);
            }

            public void println(final String string) 
            {
                logger.warn(string);
            }
        };
    }
```

and set it to the appropriate streams like this:

```
System.setOut(createLoggingProxy(System.out));
System.setErr(createLoggingProxy(System.err));
```

where `logger` is an instance of `org.apache.log4j.Logger`

Comment: Really helpful solution!